# Cambiar el valor dependiendo de una comparación en un objeto

Tags: javascript

Buenas madrugadas comunidad, tengo ahora el siguiente detalle, como hago para verificar que si el parámetro activo de un array es true su id cambie a undefined??

```js
const programa:
[
{id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 42, activo: true}
{id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false} 
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false}
]

//Quede asi:
const programa:
[
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 42, activo: true}
{id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false} 
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false}
]
```

Comment: Te diría que falta contexto.
¿estamos hablando de una aplicación de back de front?¿orientada a eventos?¿estructurada? ....

Comment: Es parte del front amigo @E.rick, espero puedas ayudarme con esta petición

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable esta mal asignada. `const programa = []`

Ejemplo:

```javascript
const programa = [
{id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true},
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true},
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 42, activo: true},
{id: 110, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false},
{id: 111, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false},
]

programa.forEach(el =>{
    if(el.activo){
        el.id = undefined;
    }
});

console.log(programa)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mi amigo @ABC ya quedo resuelto esa parte, de verdad agradezco tu tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar un forEach para recorrer el arreglo, y dentro del mismo arreglo sólo  usas una condicional para revisar si activo es true, y si es true cambias el parámetro id a undefined.

```js
const arr = [
{'id': 110, 'id_programa_educativo': 40, 'activo': true},
{'id': 111, 'id_programa_educativo': 40, 'activo': true},
{'id': 112, 'id_programa_educativo': 40, 'activo': false},
{'id': 113, 'id_programa_educativo': 40, 'activo': false},
{'id': 114, 'id_programa_educativo': 40, 'activo': false},
]

arr.forEach(element => {
  if(element.activo){
    element.id = undefined
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mi amigo @Jorge Almada de verdad agradezco tu tiempo.